# RadioGroup issue in listview

Tags: android, listview, radio-group

Im working on trivia application, and displaying questions in a listview with 4 radio buttons for each question. Here is my XML code

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"        
    android:id="@+id/radioButtonLayout">
<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:visibility="gone">

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioID_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:saveEnabled="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioID_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:saveEnabled="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioID_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:saveEnabled="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioID_4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:saveEnabled="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
</RadioGroup>    
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how i'm implementing the selection of radio buttons. getView method is here.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mObjects.size();
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_option, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.radioButtonLayout = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

            holder.radioButtonFirst = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioID_1);
            holder.radioButtonSecond = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioID_2);
            holder.radioButtonThird = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioID_3);
            holder.radioButtonFourth = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioID_4);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }   
        holder.radioButtonFirst.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.radioButtonSecond.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.radioButtonThird.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.radioButtonFourth.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

                holder.radioButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.checkboxLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.radioButtonFirst.setChecked(firstItemChecked[position]);
                holder.radioButtonSecond.setChecked(secondItemChecked[position]);
                holder.radioButtonThird.setChecked(thirdItemChecked[position]);
                holder.radioButtonFourth.setChecked(fourthItemChecked[position]);
                holder.radioButtonFirst.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(
                            CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                                firstItemChecked[position] = true;

                            } else {
                                firstItemChecked[position] = false;

                            }                               
                        }
                    });
            holder.radioButtonSecond.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(
                        CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        secondItemChecked[position] = true;

                    } else {
                        secondItemChecked[position] = false;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.radioButtonThird.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(
                        CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                                thirdItemChecked[position] = true;

                            } else {
                                thirdItemChecked[position] = false;

                            }

                        }
                    });
            holder.radioButtonFourth.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(
                        CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                                fourthItemChecked[position] = true;

                            } else {
                                fourthItemChecked[position] = false;

                            }

                        }
                    });
        return view;
    }
```

- Right now application having 5 questions and mObjects.size() is 5 in getCount method. even though getview method is getting called more than 5 times. why its so?
- after selecting the First radio button i scrolled the listview down and up, when i scrolled up for viewing first question(the one i selected the first radio button for answering) its losing the focus and displaying as unchecked. and again i tried to check the first option this time unable to select the first radio button. once i go to second option by clicking second radio button and tried, first one is working fine.

While debugging im always getting firstItemchecked(0)(first question first option) as true, even its coming with unselected.

Struggling with this issue more than 4 days. Please help me friends. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try making your code more easier to read. For example I replaced all your listeners like this :

```
holder.radioButtonFirst.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChange(position));
holder.radioButtonSecond.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChange(position));
holder.radioButtonThird.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChange(position));
holder.radioButtonFourth.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChange(position));
...
}
private class CheckChange implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private int position;
    private CheckChange(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioID_1:
            firstItemChecked[position] = isChecked;
            break;
        case R.id.radioID_2:
            secondItemChecked[position] = isChecked;
            break;
        case R.id.radioID_3:
            thirdItemChecked[position] = isChecked;
            break;
        case R.id.radioID_4:
            fourthItemChecked[position] = isChecked;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, are you sure that firstItemChecked[0] is not true? How do you initialize it?
I've had some issues also using setOnChangeListener on RadioButtons. Solved it using onClickListeners instead.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes im very sure firstItemChecked[0] is true once i click first radio button from first question and here is the array for each checked. true means its checked. I checked first radio button and it became true. and i scroll down to select 3rd one it became checked. when i scroll again to select 4th one issue raised, i selected first radio button but i couldnt select it, it keep coming as un checked state, i make the second radio button for 4th question as checked and i went back to first radio button for 4th question it worked fine.

Comment: and when i scroll up it again firstItemChecked[0] is unchecked even though value is true. don't know what's going on. Here is the Array value for 1st, 3rd and 4th questions radio button selected. [true, false, false, false, false]
[true, false, true, false, false]
[true, false, true, true, false]

Comment: how to track for unckecked status when onclicklistener implemented?

Comment: so... you have 5 questions... from your second comment i see that for the 1st and 3rd question you have at least 2 buttons checked... is that normal? setting 2 radio buttons from same group to true?

Comment: i dont understand whats causing issue. when i try to check an radio button after answering first two questions, its not coming as selected(i meant the selection of particular radio button is not coming properly) please help me friends.